# Inputting chars in a string until the next one is an integer - C

Tags: c, scanf

I'm trying to find the best way to get this kind of input:
"Word1 word2 1 2 3 4 -1"
Basically I want to save "This is a string" in a string and add the numbers to a variable sum until they reach -1.

I've tried with

```
scanf("%s %s", &string1, &string2);
```

It doesn't work properly.

Comment: What to do with `He orders 4 beers ... 3 2 1 0 -1`?

Comment: Can you give another example input and (intended) output?

Comment: Do the `1` in `Word1` and `2` in `Word2` count as strings or numbers?

Comment: how do you plan to fix the number of elements in input?

Comment: It's like this:
"John Smith mark1 mark2 mark3 -1"
Where john smith is the string and mark1 mark2 mark3 are integers that I should calculate the average (i must keep getting marks until the users enters -1).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler There will be just 2 words: name and surname

Comment: OK: is there a plausible upper-bound on the number of numbers? Like say 16, 32, 64? You can do it with `fgets()` and `sscanf()` using `%n` to find where the conversion has gotten to in the input.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler The number of numbers can be maximum 6.

Comment: @SouravGhosh The number of marks can be 1 - 6 so the scanf wouldn't work if the marks were less than 6, would it?

Comment: @Arlind . right you are. my bad.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  char line[4096];
  while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin) != 0)
  {
    char name1[32];
    char name2[32];
    int score = 0;
    int offset = 0;
    int length = 0;
    int number;
    if (sscanf(line + length, "%s%n", name1, &offset) != 1)
        break;
    length += offset;
    if (sscanf(line + length, "%s%n", name2, &offset) != 1)
        break;
    length += offset;
    while (sscanf(line + length, "%d%n", &number, &offset) == 1 && number != -1)
    {
      length += offset;
      score += number;
    }
    printf("%s %s %d\n", name1, name2, score);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Data file:

```
John Smith 1 2 4 5
John Sutton 2 4 6 8 9 -1
Maggie Smith 9 8 9 8 9 9 -1
```

Sample output:

```
John Smith 12
John Sutton 29
Maggie Smith 52
```

You can fix it to object if there isn't a -1 at the end (though it really isn't needed, witness the first line of input), and similarly you can object if there are more than 6 entries, etc.

Or, if you want to use `fscanf()`, then you can do this (which gives the same output for the given input as the original version):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  char name1[32];
  char name2[32];
  int score[7];
  int nv;
  while ((nv = fscanf(stdin, "%31s %31s %d %d %d %d %d %d %d",
                name1, name2, &score[0], &score[1], &score[2], &score[3],
                &score[4], &score[5], &score[6])) > 2)
  {
    int total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < nv - 2; i++)
    {
        if (score[i] == -1)
          break;
        total += score[i];
    }
    printf("%s %s %d\n", name1, name2, total);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Note that this code knows how many numbers were successfully read (`nv - 2`), and proceeds accordingly.  Now your task is to go messing with the data file to see what other formats it accepts, and then decide whether this is better.  You can also use a hybrid program, using `fgets()` to read a line and a `sscanf()` analogous to the `fscanf()` in the second program to read all the values at once.